# How to exit a method in Phaser3 only when the played timeline is finished?

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm quite new in Phaser, but I've already done a bunch of ionic/angular app.

One of my object has a method that will be called by the main scene:

```
powerOff() {
    let easing = 'Cubic'
    let overallDuration = 500
    let visiblePauseDuration = 100

    let flashDuration = overallDuration - visiblePauseDuration / 2

    this.scene.tweens.timeline({
      tweens: [
        {
          targets: this,
          duration: 0,
          tint: 0xff0000,
          ease: easing,
        },
        {
          targets: this,
          duration: flashDuration,
          tint: 0xffffff,
          ease: easing,
        },
        {
          targets: this,
          duration: visiblePauseDuration,
          tint: 0xff0000,
          ease: easing,
        },
        {
          targets: this,
          duration: flashDuration,
          tint: 0xffffff,
          ease: easing,
        },
        {
          targets: this,
          duration: visiblePauseDuration,
          tint: 0xff0000,
          ease: easing,
          onComplete: () => {
            this.scene.sound.play(MainScene.POWER_DOWN)
          },
        },
        {
          targets: this,
          duration: flashDuration,
          tint: 0xf54242,
          ease: easing,
        },
      ],
    })

    this.poweredUp = false
  }
```

The thing is: I need to exit this method only when the timeline has completed.

Is there some await/async support? Or at least promises ?

The scene will call this method on a lot of different objects, and I need that they are not done in parallel but sequentially.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeline = this.scene.tweens.timeline({
    /*TWEENS*/
})
//Timeline complete event listener
timeline.addListener("complete", function(){
    //Do something when tweens are complete
}, this);
```